# Ionic 2 Toggle preventdefault

Tags: angular, ionic2, dom-events

I have a Toggle switch. I want not to check or uncheck the toggle at first. To be precise, toggle will be checked or unchecked based on a server response which is why I need to use `preventDefault`.

I have used `ionChange()` instead of `click()` event handler. But with `ionChange` handler, the `cancelable` or `defaultPrevented` property does not exists. So, it raises error that `preventDefault()` is not a function. However, with simple click handler, it does not raise any error but does not work either. I have also tried with `stopPropagation()`.

Here is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="appliance.state" (ionChange)="applianceChange($event)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'appliances',
  templateUrl: 'appliances.html'
})
export class ApplianceModule {
  constructor(){}

 applianceChange(event: Event){
   event.preventDefault(); 
 }
}
```

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

What if you disable the toggle and change it programmatically.
The example code will toggle the ion-toggle to checked and unchecked every 1500 ms

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-page',
  template: `<ion-toggle #toggle disabled=""></toggle>`
})
export class MyPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('toggle') ionToggle: Toggle;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.ionToggle._checked = !(this.ionToggle._checked);
    }, 1500);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it:

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (ionChange)="applianceChange($event)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>

applianceChange(ev){
    if(ev._checked == this.isChecked){
        callAction();
    }
}

callAction(){
    ...
     this.appliance.state = this.isChecked //it's important to change value so it can react properly on ionChange
    ...
}
```

You need to declare `isChecked` as boolean and give it a value in `ngOnit` or constructor when you make your server call. I hope this helps to somebody